# Does the share price always rise after a SPAC announce merger with a target company?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Does the share price always rise after a SPAC (special purpose acquisition company) announces merger with a target company?

I feel the only purpose of a SPAC is to merge with a target company and bring the target company to public.

So, I assume the share price of the SPAC will always rise following the merger announcement.

However, does the announcement always happen after 4:00pm EST?

If this is true, then it is still difficult for retail investors to buy the shares immediately following the announcement?

Comment: Perhaps this [might be of interest](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/2020-is-the-year-of-the-spac-yet-traditional-ipos-offer-better-returns-report-finds-2020-09-04).

Comment: Yes. This article is very useful. Thanks

Comment: @BobBaerker For a SPAC merger, retail investors can buy the stock early in the SPAC merger. In a traditional IPO, institutional investors are the first in line. Do you feel this is an advantage of a SPAC merger for retail investors?

Comment: I don't follow SPAC situations so I have no awareness of how they behave pre/post merger.